# InDesign Script extract stories if paragraph style

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

Struggling with the below script. I modified a script found so that it extracts all stories as txt files and  saves the txt file with the filename of the the text in the paragraph.

It turned out we didn't want all stories extracted however the ones we did want had a set paragraph style for the first paragraph of story.

The part im struggling with is the syntax of the if statement that checks what the currently applied paragraph style is.

any help appreciated, sorry if my problem is unclear

```
main();
function main(){
//Make certain that user interaction (display of dialogs, etc.) is turned on.
app.scriptPreferences.userInteractionLevel = UserInteractionLevels.interactWithAll;
if(app.documents.length != 0){
    if (app.activeDocument.stories.length != 0){
        myDisplayDialog();
    }
    else{
        alert("The document does not contain any text. Please open a document containing text and try again.");
    }
}
else{
    alert("No documents are open. Please open a document and try again.");
}
}
function myDisplayDialog(){
with(myDialog = app.dialogs.add({name:"ExportAllStories"})){
    //Add a dialog column.
    myDialogColumn = dialogColumns.add()    
    with(myDialogColumn){
        with(borderPanels.add()){
            staticTexts.add({staticLabel:"Export as:"});
            with(myExportFormatButtons = radiobuttonGroups.add()){
                radiobuttonControls.add({staticLabel:"Text Only", checkedState:true});
                radiobuttonControls.add({staticLabel:"RTF"});
                radiobuttonControls.add({staticLabel:"InDesign Tagged Text"});
            }
        }
    }
    myReturn = myDialog.show();
    if (myReturn == true){
        //Get the values from the dialog box.
        myExportFormat = myExportFormatButtons.selectedButton;
        myDialog.destroy;
        myFolder= Folder.selectDialog ("Choose a Folder");
        if((myFolder != null)&&(app.activeDocument.stories.length !=0)){
            myExportAllStories(myExportFormat, myFolder);
        }
    }
    else{
        myDialog.destroy();
    }
}
}
//myExportStories function takes care of exporting the stories.
//myExportFormat is a number from 0-2, where 0 = text only, 1 = rtf, and 3 = tagged text.
//myFolder is a reference to the folder in which you want to save your files.
function myExportAllStories(myExportFormat, myFolder){
for(myCounter = 0; myCounter < app.activeDocument.stories.length; myCounter++){
    myStory = app.activeDocument.stories.item(myCounter);
    myID = myStory.id;
    switch(myExportFormat){
        case 0:
            myFormat = ExportFormat.textType;
            myExtension = ".txt"
            break;
        case 1:
            myFormat = ExportFormat.RTF;
            myExtension = ".rtf"
            break;
        case 2:
            myFormat = ExportFormat.taggedText;
            myExtension = ".txt"
            break;
    }
    if(myStory.paragraphs[0].appliedParagraphStyle = "PRODUCT HEADING"){

        myFileName = myStory.paragraphs[0].contents;
        myFilePath = myFolder + "/" + myFileName;
        myFile = new File(myFilePath);
        myStory.exportFile(myFormat, myFile);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `appliedParagraphStyle` is `[Object ParagraphStyle]`, so you need to compare it against either another paragraph style (i.e., `app.activeDocument.paragraphStyles.item("PRODUCT HEADING")` which *does* return a paragraph style), or compare the *names* of the styles.

Also, **do not use `=` to test**. A single `=` is 'apply'; to test for (in)equality, use a double `==`. (Javascript also has a '*strictly* equals' comparison: `===`, but in this case it should not be used.)

Your script will work if you change the comparison line to

```
if (myStory.paragraphs[0].appliedParagraphStyle.name == "PRODUCT HEADING")
```

---

Additionally, the line

```
myFileName = myStory.paragraphs[0].contents;
```

grabs the entire paragraph to use for a file name, and usually this will include the paragraph return at the end. (The exception is when this paragraph is the last one in a story.) Since you use this string as a new file name, you must remove the paragraph return if it's there. That can be done in several ways, but the easiest is to use a RegEx replace:

```
myFileName = myStory.paragraphs[0].contents.replace(/\s*$/,'');
```

because that will also remove all stray spaces and tabs at the end for free.

Comment: Excellent thank you. I knew I was close. However I now have a different issue. It works but the filenames have a softreturn on the end so Finder(mac) sees each file as .txt however when editing filename it is correct. How could I grab the contents of the first paragraph but take a character off the end?

Comment: Ha, I missed that. Added!

Comment: Thank you I have marked this as the answer as it is for my original problem. however I tried adding another .replace line to remove slashes however it is throwing an error. How would I also remove '/' from the first paragraph to use as filename?

Comment: Ah -- the forward slash is a special character in Javascript's RegEx: it starts and ends the expression! So you have to *escape* it with a backslash. To match just a single slash, you'd use something like this unintentional ASCII art: `/\//`. To remove any number of them, use `..replace(/\//g, '')`.

Comment: Thank you this now works. We have another issue though but without knowing what It is I can't ask for help.